# Left-, center-, and right-aligned text on the same line

Tags: html, css, webkit

Is there a way to have left-, center-, and right-aligned text on the same line with HTML/CSS, under the following conditions?

1. The left and right pieces of text will be short, but I do not know their length in advance.
2. The center piece of text may be long enough to wrap.
3. The center piece of text should appear EXACTLY in the center.
4. The center piece of text should not overlap the left or right pieces of text.

The obvious solution of using 3 divs with the two of them floating left and right works pretty well, except that the center piece of text is not centered exactly (for example, if the left piece of text is longer than the right, the center appears centered just right of the absolute center).

I only need a solution that works on WebKit. Any ideas?

**Edit** - This is what I have so far...

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="center">Center text</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#center {
    text-align: center;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: hmmm no i only know a JS solution where you take left or right width and use it for the other side... only then the centered text is in exaclty center. without widths you not able to do that only HTML and CSS.... you can use % width like 10% - 80% - 10% but this are fixed width depending on container

Comment: can you post the code you're working on?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a table. Exactly what data are you trying to put there?

Comment: It's the header of a page with the page number on the left, the title in the center, and a link on the right. A JS solution might work though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to "trick" the left column into being as wide as the right, by copying the text from the right into the left column.  Why?  When the center column needs to wrap in order to maintain center with respect to the whole table it will need to wrap as if both other columns are the same width.  You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/n5eSB/ by adjusting the size of the `Result` panel.  Note that this does make your table one line taller due to the hidden content.  I don't know all the details of your implementation, so you will need to make adjustments (overflow hidden, negative margins, position relative, etc) to get this to fit into the page, but it should get you started:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="d1">
            left
            <div class="copy">right text</div>
        </td>
        <td class="d2">
            center text that is long enough to force a word wrap!
        </td>
        <td class="d3">right text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.d1 {
    text-align: left;
}
.d2 {
    text-align:center;
}
.d3 {
    text-align:right;
}
.copy {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.copy, .d3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

solution with clear divs

https://jsfiddle.net/LaL92q88/1/

```
<div style="float: left">Left Text</div>
<div style="float: right">Right Text</div>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100px;">Centered Text</div>
```

Comment: text-align: center in the last line is needed

`<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; text-align: center">Centered Text</div>`

Comment: @guido - to clarify your suggestion: `text-align: center` is needed if ALL lines of the central text are to be centered (ragged left and right edges); if the goal is to have the wrapped lines be left-justified with the first line (a central "box" that has equal space on left and right, but left-justified text within that box, like a typical paragraph), might not need that. [In this case, the combination of "auto" margin, and specified width, are enough to center the text box.]

Comment: I was using this approach for paginated data with next and previous links.  My problem with this is that if the left or right text was blank; then the centered text would move.  Is there a simple solution to that?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the display:table(-row/-cell) properties:

http://jsfiddle.net/WYxek/

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="d1">left text</div>
        <div class="d2">center text</div>
        <div class="d3">right text</div>
    </div>
</div>



.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.tr {
    display:table-row;
}
.d1 {
    display:table-cell;
    width:25%;
}
.d2 {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
}
.d3 {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:right;
    width:25%;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but it prevents the center text from using more than 50% of the full width, even if the left and right are shorter than 25% each.